# nvidia backlight and flickering issue Mac 2010 LOKI

Tags: release-loki, graphics, nvidia

After installing the Nvidia proprietary drivers (the nuovo drivers had problems with flickering on the external monitor) the backlight brightness could not be set anymore (neither with keys nor with power settings).

Tried many hints but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1):

Instead install the `nvidiabl` module to make `/sys/class/backlight/nvidia_backlight/` work again.

1. Download `nvidiabl` from https://github.com/guillaumezin/nvidiabl
2. Go to folder `nvidiabl-master`
3. Edit `nvidiabl-module.c` line 213 and replace `strnicmp` to `strncasecmp`
4. `make && make install`
5. Reboot to make buttons work again (via powersave settings it should work right away)

Now you should have a module called `nvidiabl` loaded and the brightness setting works again!